# Node: import object array from another js file?

Tags: node.js, express

In a file called data.js, I have a big object array:

```
var arr = [ {prop1: value, prop2: value},...]
```

I'd like to use this array into my Node.js app, but code like

```
require('./data.js')
```

doesn't help. I know how to export *functions*, but I'm lost when it comes to "importing" *arrays*. How do I add the data.js file to my app.js?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Local variables (var whatever) are not exported and local to the module. You can define your array on the exports object in order to allow to import it. You could create a .json file as well, if your array only contains simple objects.

data.js:

```
module.exports = ['foo','bar',3];
```

import.js

```
console.log(require('./data')); //output: [ 'foo', 'bar', 3 ]
```

[Edit]

If you require a module (for the first time), its code is executed and the *exports* object is returned and cached. For all further calls to `require()`, only the cached context is returned.

You can nevertheless modify objects from within a modules code. Consider this module:

```
module.exports.arr = [];
module.exports.push2arr = function(val){module.exports.arr.push(val);};
```

and calling code:

```
var mod = require("./mymodule");
mod.push2arr(2);
mod.push2arr(3);
console.log(mod.arr); //output: [2,3]
```

Comment: This works as expected. But how do I export the array _after_ it is assigned to _arr_ in the data.js file?

Comment: I'm using __module.exports = arr;__ in my data.js, and the console.log statement prints as expected, when I __var arr = require('./data');__

Answer (score 6):

> *I know how to export functions, [...]*

An array, or really any value, can be exported the same as `function`s, by modifying `module.exports` or `exports`:

```
var arr = [ {prop1: value, prop2: value},...];

exports.arr = arr;
```

```
var arr = require('./data').arr;
```

Comment: Following your example, to the data.js, I appended:
     __exports.arr = arr;__
to the app.js, I added:
     __var arr = require('./data.js').arr;__

but when I call __arr__ in the Node console, I get "undefined" instead of an array. ??

Comment: @user1891836 What do mean by "*call arr*?" If you're testing from the REPL, have it evaluate `var arr = require('./data').arr;` directly. Having that line in `app.js` will only accomplish making it available within those 2 files, not to a 3rd file or the REPL without them requiring it themselves.

Comment: Evaluating the var statement through REPL throws an _Error: Cannot find module './data'_

Comment: @user1891836 You may need to adjust the path while using the REPL. For it, `require()` paths will be relative to the current working directory, which you can get from [`process.cwd()`](http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_cwd).

Answer (score 6):

> You can directly get JSON or JSON array from any file in NODEJS there
>   is no need to export it from a JS script

```
    [ {
        prop1: value, 
        prop2: value
      },
      {
        prop1: val,
        prop2: val2
      },
      ...
   ]
```

Store it to a JSON file suppose **test.json**

> Now you can export it as given below its very simple.

```
let data = require('./test.json');
```

Answer (score 3):

You can simply wrap your array in a function.

```
// myArray.js
export default function iDoReturnAnArray() {
  return ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'];
}

// main.js 
import iDoReturnAnArray from './path/to/myArray';

const unwrappedArray = iDoReturnAnArray();

console.log(unwrappedArray); // ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use destructuring to solve your problem.

In file1.js, we create an object array:

```
var arr = [{ prop1: "beep", prop2: "boop" }];
```

Then we do the following to export:

```
module.exports = { arr };
```

Then in another file, file2.js, we require the array from file1

```
const f1 = require("./file1");
```

Log the result to test

```
console.log(f1.arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

**data.js**

```
 var arr = [ {prop1: value, prop2: value}]
 module.exports = { arr }
```

**node.js**

```
const {arr} = require('./data')
console.log(arr)
```

*simple!*