# I need to access data from a different javascript file, and change it into a string

Tags: javascript, string

I need to access data in this format to use it with Chart.js:

```
var dataArrays = {
  id: 1,
  time : [1543855884861,1543855889279],
  parsetTimestamp: ["3 Dec 2018 17:51:24","3 Dec 2018 17:51:29"],
  temperature: [23.4,24.4],
  humidity: [38,40],
  light: [1000,1100],
  soil: [750,800],
  fanIn: [1,0],
  fanOut: [0,1],
  ledIntensity: [1024,1024]
 }
```

I need to get the data from a different js file, formatted like this:

```js
var data = [{
    name: 'tube',
    time: 1546614557692,
    temperature: 23,
    humidity: 49,
    light: 1718,
    soil: 1024,
    fanIn: 0,
    fanOut: 0,
    ledIntensity: 1024
  },
  {
    name: 'tube',
    time: 1546614557697,
    temperature: 23,
    humidity: 49,
    light: 1721,
    soil: 1024,
    fanIn: 0,
    fanOut: 0,
    ledIntensity: 1024
  }
]
```

I think I can add data from different variables like this:

```
var dataArrays.time = [data1.time, data2.time];
```

but I don't have two variables, I only have one with all the data, and it's located in a different file.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I have noticed there is a difference between 'id' and 'name', I need to use 'name' from the variable data, I'll fix that in my code

Comment: So you want the object property values in `dataArrays` to consist of object properties from `data`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply want to merge the objects of the array, you can use `Array.prototype.reduce` to do so.

Just iterate through the keys of the object contained in the array `data` and merge the duplicate keys and put them in array and assign it to the accumulated `merged` object.

```js
var data = [{
    name: 'tube',
    time: 1546614557692,
    temperature: 23,
    humidity: 49,
    light: 1718,
    soil: 1024,
    fanIn: 0,
    fanOut: 0,
    ledIntensity: 1024
  },
  {
    name: 'tube',
    time: 1546614557697,
    temperature: 23,
    humidity: 49,
    light: 1721,
    soil: 1024,
    fanIn: 0,
    fanOut: 0,
    ledIntensity: 1024
  }
]

var merged = data.reduce((acc, ele) =>{
for(key in ele){
    acc[key] = acc[key] ? acc[key].concat(ele[key]) : [ele[key]];
}
return acc;
},{});

console.log(merged);
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked. The only problem I have is that the var data is stored in a different file, and because of the amount of data I will receive I don't want to have to write it over, can I reference it in this file in some way?

Comment: What I probably should say is that the files are in different folders aswell, one is in `Source code/Frondend` and the other file is in `Source code/Server_Backend`

Comment: @DaanR this answer might help you, or you can also serve it over http as a JSON? so that the front end code can parse it :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23897429/node-import-object-array-from-another-js-file

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can always create variables according to your needs.
Example:

```
var data1 = data[0];
var data2 = data[1];
```

And then you can use it as how you've shown in the question.

For accessing different javascript file, if this is in a node runtime, you can use `require`, if not [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3244361/can-i-access-variables-from-another-file) might help you

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use reduce function to combine the `data` array into one combine object `dataArray`

```
var res = {
    id: 1,
    time : [],
    parsetTimestamp: [],
    temperature: [],
    humidity: [],
    light: [],
    soil: [],
    fanIn: [],
    fanOut: [],
    ledIntensity: []
};
dataArray = data.reduce(function(res, cur) {
   res.id = 1,
   res.time.push(cur.time);
   res.temperature.push(cur.temparature);
   res.humidity.push(cur.humidity);
   // etc etc

   return res;  // have to return in reduce
} , res); // initial value
```